# Writing on a stream while it is processed by a speech recognition engine

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, stream, speech-recognition

I'm using C# and .Net 4.5

I have a MemoryStream which I gave to the Microsoft Speech Recognition Engine, but if fails to recognize the stream.

The problem is that the stream is written by another Thread while the speech recognition accesses it, since I handed a Stream.synchronized(stream) object to the speech recognition the access itself is not the problem, it is thread-safe.
I think there is a problem with the position pointer. The pointer is, of course, at the end of the newly written data which thread 1 wrote onto the stream. So thread 1 always writes and pushes the pointer to the end and the result is that the pointer points always to the last element within the stream.
The recognition engine, thread 2, thinks there is nothing new to read since the pointer is at the end.

The only solution can image is to write a new class derived from the stream class which has two separate position pointers. One for the writing and one for the reading.

Is there any other solution?

Regards,

Max

Edit: Some Code:

(Sre Thread)

```
SpeechAudioFormatInfo info = new SpeechAudioFormatInfo(16000, AudioBitsPerSample.Sixteen, AudioChannel.Mono);
sre.SetInputToAudioStream(stream, info);
sre.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
```

(UDP Thread)

```
test.Write(messagePart, 0, messagePart.Length);
        test.Flush();
```

Comment: Maybe. Why do you want these two pieces of data interwoven on the same stream like this?

Comment: There is no need for me to save the sent audio date, I just want to receive it and forward it into the speech recognition.

Saving the audio data also causes the problem that I cannot have a continous speech recognition, which is required for my program.

Comment: Why not use two streams?  It would probably help if you included the failing code.

Comment: I'll include some code in the evening, when I'm at home.

How can I bind two streams to the same data? Copy stream or something similar would not solve my problem since there is incoming data all the time.